# All possible combinations from 5 positions with sum 6

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 5 positions, each position can have a possible number from 0 to 6.  How to calculate or find all the possible combinations that has a sum of 6 from these 5 positions?

e.g.
11112
11121
11211
12111
21111
01113
01131
.
00006
00060
etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stars-and-bars.  $\binom{5+6-1}{6-1}=\binom{10}{5}$

Comment: Please write what you have tried.

Comment: For Stars and Bars theory, see 
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @user2661923 If I follow that theory, it would be 10 choose 4 then?

Comment: Yes, that's right, $~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +x_4 + x_5 = 6~$, where $~x_1, \cdots, x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}~$ has $~\displaystyle \binom{6 + [5-1]}{5-1} = \binom{10}{4}~$ solutions.

Comment: @user2661923  Thank you!